# php cURL returning all lowercase

Tags: php, xml, curl, soap

I'm connecting to an API and need to retrieve XML data. I get the response, but the problem is that all keys are lowercase. If I test the request using SoapUI, it responds as expected so I've narrowed it down to my server and my code. This is my request:

```
$headers = array(
        "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
        "Accept: text/xml",
        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
        "Pragma: no-cache",
        "SOAPAction: http://XYZDOMAIN.com.au/" . $func,
        "Content-length: " . strlen($xml_post_string),
        "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate"
    ); //SOAPAction: your op URL
    // PHP cURL  for https connection with auth

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string); // the SOAP request
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip,deflate");

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    if ($errno = curl_errno($ch)) {
        $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
        echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}";
    }

    $return = gzdecode($response);

    print_r($return);
```

The `print_r` at the end is there just for me to see what it returns, of course. The problem is that ALL of the keys returned in the XML are lowercase and it's messing up the rest of my code. 
This used to work just fine until a month ago and I have no idea what changed, but the only possible change was something on the server.

Can anybody point me in the right direction as to why the response is being changed to lowercase? Thank you!

Comment: I imagine it might have something to do with the gzip compression (results will often be slightly smaller when compressing all lowercase characters)

Comment: Did you recently upgrade to PHP 7.1+? And don't forget to close the curl connection (nothing to do with the question, but worth noting).

Comment: @Daniel I'm with you, but this seems to be happening just for us, so it's our server. Also, the code DID work until now so what changed? I'm starting to think it's something with the curl headers, but can't pinpoint it

Comment: And you're sure the `$xml_post_string` is identical in your code, and when you manually check with SoapUI?

Comment: @Zeke I'm not sure about any server-side changes, it's a managed VPS with cPanel. We're using php 5.4.37. curl is closed later in the code after all of the processing, this is just a small part of a much larger class.

Comment: @Daniel yes, the $xml_post_string is 100% identical, it was originally copied from the SoapUI request. I just checked again to be sure and yes, it's the same

Comment: Try changing the `Accept` Header from `text/xml` to `application/xml`

Comment: @Daniel that was one of the first changes I had tried, no luck

Comment: Afraid I'm out of ideas then - quite a challenge you got yourself. I'll leave an upvote and get back to you if I get an idea

Comment: I see, that's good to know. 5.4.37 is too old though, maybe an upgrade in cPanel MultiPHP Manager would be ideal. Usually WHM (I manage a server with WHM/cPanel) allows for multiple PHP installations. Anyway, I don't think that's the problem... but [here's something interesting someone else asked 1 month ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48089681/php-curl-with-json-header-returning-lowercase-data) and it seems that they have the same issue using JSON... but using XML over JSON works fine... I don't know... it is very strange.

Comment: [I also found this](https://curl.haxx.se/mail/curlphp-2004-02/0052.html) but it's too old (2004)...

Comment: @Zeke I've seen both, but neither helped. :) as for php version, I know it's old but there are other reasons why we can't upgrade. However, I believe this is irrelevant and won't resolve the issue since it worked before...

Comment: Totally agreed about the PHP version, I don't think it has anything to do if it's for those versions. In any case, it's a great question, I am as shocked as you are. I left an upvote and I hope someone comes up with a solution.

Answer (score 5):

The PHP version is using HTTP 2 instead of 1.1, and the HTTP 2 specification requires that headers are lower-cased. So that seems to be what's causing the difference.

https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7540.html#HttpHeaders - "Just as in HTTP/1.x, header field names are strings of ASCII characters that are compared in a case-insensitive fashion. However, header field names MUST be converted to lowercase prior to their encoding in HTTP/2. A request or response containing uppercase header field names MUST be treated as malformed (Section 8.1.2.6)."

You may force http version to 1.1:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);`

to make sure you receive your headers in mixed case.

Comment: Working fine; in my case on server in response header all keys were in lowercase which causing issue. after setting up http version it worked well

Comment: Even if forcing 1.1 I am getting lowercase headers..